# How can i hide the back button using template 10?

Tags: c#, uwp, template10

I want to use template 10 to develop my app, but I dont know how can I hide the back button once I pass from one page to another, like for example passing from a login page to my main page.
With template 10 it always show the back button, I know how to prevent from going back, but still I can see the damn back button on the shell, I dont wish to see it.
How could I hide it?

Comment: You can do something like `SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Hidden;` refer this for more about back event, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/navigation-history-and-backwards-navigation

Comment: Yeah I've done that, but it pollutes my code-behind, I wish to maintain everything within the viewmodel, with Template 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClearHistory` is located on the `HamburgerButtonInfo` as a DP and if that isn't enough you can thru the `NavigationService` call ClearHistory as well which looks like `public void ClearHistory() => FrameFacade.BackStack.Clear();` in the source so you know what it actually calls...

Comment: glad to help  you out :)

Comment: I didnt know you were a Pilot, I'm an Air Traffic Controller man!!! :) so cool to meet someone in the airspace community that loves to code!!!

Comment: What airspace? I am out of houston

Comment: Sorry I m not good at my english I meant.  That we are from the community.  Im an air traffic controller and as You have in your profile you are a pilot. Can I contact you? Look me at skype Quico20.